# Loading data into dynamic partition takes lot of time

Tags: dynamic, hive, partition

When i run hive query with dynamic partition i see that loading data into partition is time consuming process.

Given that i have data only with date = 2015-03-15 and locale = us and run query with dynamic partition, i see -

```
Loading data to table schema.tablename partition (date=null, locale=null)
Loading partition {date=2015-01-25,locale=us}
Loading partition {date=2015-02-12,locale=mx}
Loading partition {date=2015-03-17,locale=us}
Loading partition {date=2014-12-31,locale=tw}
...
...
```

I see lot of stats been gathered here though i have setting 
           `SET hive.stats.autogather=false;`

I would like to know is there any setting/anything i can do to minimize the time taking for loading data in to partition. Please help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to know is there any setting/anything i can do to minimize the time taking for loading data in to partition.

Comment: @Balaji did you find any solution for it?? I am facing same issue.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue...please help me if you find any solution